# como poner fija la cabecera de mi tabla

Tags: php, html, css

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="es"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="es"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="es"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="es"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <title>Ejemplo de Edici&oacute;n en el lugar con jQuery</title>

    <style>

    .contenedor{margin:28px auto;width:960px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:12px;
        }
    table {width:95%;box-shadow:0 0 10px #ddd;text-align:left; background-color: #F2F2F2;}
    th {padding:5px;background:#555;color:#fff}
    td {padding:5px;border:solid #ddd;border-width:0 0 1px;}
        .editable span{display:block;}
        .editable span:hover {background:url(images/edit.png) 90% 50% no-repeat;cursor:pointer}

        td input{height:24px;width:200px;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:0 5px;margin:0;border-radius:6px;vertical-align:middle}
        a.enlace{display:inline-block;width:24px;height:24px;margin:0 0 0 5px;overflow:hidden;text-indent:-999em;vertical-align:middle}
            .guardar{background:url(images/save2.png) 0 0 no-repeat}
            .cancelar{background:url(images/cancel.png) 0 0 no-repeat}

    .mensaje{display:block;text-align:center;margin:0 0 20px 0}
        .ok{display:block;padding:10px;text-align:center;background:green;color:#fff}
        .ko{display:block;padding:10px;text-align:center;background:red;color:#fff}
        h1{color:white;text-align:center}

        tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: #E6E6E6;
    color: black;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1>TODAS FACTURAS</h1>
           <input type="button" value="REFRESCAR" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick = "location='todasfac.php'"/>
        <div class="mensaje"></div>
        <table class="editinplace">
            <tr>
                <th>Cod.</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Factura</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Importe MXN</th>
                <th>Importe DLS</th>
                <th>FechaFactura</th>
                <th>FechaContrarecibo</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        /* OBTENEMOS TABLA */
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "uptodas.php?tabla=1"

        })
        .done(function(json) {
            json = $.parseJSON(json)
            for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
            {
                $('.editinplace').append(
                    "<tr><td class='id'>"+json[i].id+"</td><td data-campo='estado'><span>"+json[i].estado+"</span></td><td data-campo='factura'><span>"+json[i].factura+"</s pan></td><td data-campo='cliente'><span>"+json[i].cliente+"</span></td><td data-campo='importemn'><span>"+json[i].importemn+"</span></td><td data-campo='importe_dls'><span>"+json[i].importe_dls+"</span></td><td data-campo='fechafactura'><span>"+json[i].fechafactura+"</span></td><td class='editable' data-campo='fechacontrarecibo'><span>"+json[i].fechacontrarecibo+"</span></td></tr>");
            }
        });

        var td,campo,valor,id;
        $(document).on("click","td.editable span",function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("td:not(.id)").removeClass("editable");
            td=$(this).closest("td");
            campo=$(this).closest("td").data("campo");
            valor=$(this).text();
            id=$(this).closest("tr").find(".id").text();
            td.text("").html("<input type='text' name='"+campo+"' value='"+valor+"'><a class='enlace guardar' href='#'>Guardar</a><a class='enlace cancelar' href='#'>Cancelar</a>");
        });

        $(document).on("click",".cancelar",function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            td.html("<span>"+valor+"</span>");
            $("td:not(.id)").addClass("editable");
        });

        $(document).on("click",".guardar",function(e)
        {
            $(".mensaje").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'>");
            e.preventDefault();
            nuevovalor=$(this).closest("td").find("input").val();
            if(nuevovalor.trim()!="")
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "uptodas.php",
                    data: { campo: campo, valor: nuevovalor, id:id }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    $(".mensaje").html(msg);
                    td.html("<span>"+nuevovalor+"</span>");
                    $("td:not(.id)").addClass("editable");
                    setTimeout(function() {$('.ok,.ko').fadeOut('fast');}, 3000);
                });
            }
            else $(".mensaje").html("<p class='ko'>Debes ingresar un valor</p>");
        });
    });

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-266167-20");
        pageTracker._setDomainName(".martiniglesias.eu");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fijar el encabezado de la tabla, debés separar tu encabezado y cuerpo usando los nodos `<thead></thead>` y `<tbody></tbody>`. Luego, aplicás una altura específica al cuerpo, y un `overflow: auto;` en el css al `tbody`, y listo. Cuidado con el tamaño del scroll en los navegadores como IE y Firefox, pues modificarán el ancho del elemento `tbody`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
}

thead, tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

tbody tr, thead tr {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody td, thead th {
    width: 80px;  /* Optional */
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Head 1</th>
<th>Head 1</th>
<th>Head 1</th>
<th>Head 1</th>
<th>Head 1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col1</td>
<td>Col2</td>
<td>Col3</td>
<td>Col4</td>
<td>Col5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: <table class="editinplace">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Cod.</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Factura</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Importe MXN</th>
    <th>Importe DLS</th>
    <th>FechaFactura</th>
    <th>FechaContrarecibo</th>
   </tr>
  </thead> 
  </table>

Comment: {
    $('.editinplace').append(
     "<tbody><tr><td class='id'>"+json[i].id+"</td><td data-campo='estado'><span>"+json[i].estado+"</span></td><td data-campo='factura'><span>"+json[i].factura+"</s pan></td><td data-campo='cliente'><span>"+json[i].cliente+"</span></td><td data-campo='importemn'><span>"+json[i].importemn+"</span></td><td data-campo='importe_dls'><span>"+json[i].importe_dls+"</span></td><td data-campo='fechafactura'><span>"+json[i].fechafactura+"</span></td><td class='editable' data-campo='fechacontrarecibo'><span>"+json[i].fechacontrarecibo+"</span></td></tr></tbody>");
   }

Comment: thead,tbody tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {    
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

Comment: ya añadí la etiqueta <thead> <tbody> y puse en el css  ese código con position fiexed pero no me sale solo se queda pegado el encabezado de la tabla

Comment: Te agregué un código de ejemplo. Las partes importantes son el `display: block` y `overflow: auto` del `<tbody/>`.

Comment: ok muchas gracias , ya quedo